# error during update angular 10 to angular 11

Tags: angular

i'm trying to update my project from angular 10 to angular 11 version but when i run the command ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 the ide return me in log this.

What can i do?

```
While resolving: calendar@0.0.0
Found: typescript@3.7.7
node_modules/typescript
  dev typescript@"~3.7.5" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer typescript@">=4.0 <4.2" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
  dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~11.2.14" from the root project
  peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.19
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
    dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1102.19" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

i want to thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency compatibility problem.

You have Typescript 3.7 in your deps when Angular 11 requires a least 4.0.

Comment: ok , now i try to update ts and then we'll see if it work, thanks

Comment: ok i've update ts to 4.9.5 but when i run ng serve log throw error ngcc failed

Comment: For Angular 11, it should be less than 4.2. See the `typescript@">=4.0 <4.2"` in the error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this question came up top so not sure if it's still relevant but have you tried looking at: https://update.angular.io/?v=10.0-16.0 ?

This is webpage created by Angular is to guide you through updating your Angular application from version x.x.x to y.y.y They provide steps which you can check as done before continuing. I also experienced that the longer you wait with maintaining your dependencies the harder it can get to just run update.

Also, please have a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check it helped me maintaining my dependencies much easier. BUT keep in mind to update Angular always with: `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` this way the Angular updater can do stuff it needs to do instead of just updating the package version

Answer (score -1):

npm config set legacy-peer-deps true. Then try updating again. If that does not work try the below.

ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force

Comment: nope , it does't work

Comment: ok I edited it , try again

Comment: now i've all the dependecies version in the right version , i've force the upddate whit --force option and it has installed all the packages , but when i run ng serve it returns me errors in console